# Making sure that proof about limits in a metric space is correct

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through Real Analysis and I'm not sure about one of my homework exercises.

Here's the question and my proof:

Given that $\left( x_{n}\right) $ is a sequence in a metric space $X$ and
that $x\in X,$ prove that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $ if
and only if $d\left( x_{n},x\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty .$

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Assume that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty .$

I know that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that
the inequality

$d\left(x_{n},x\right)<\varepsilon $

holds for every integer $n\geq N.$

I want to show that for every $\delta >0$ there exists an integer $N$ such
that the condition

$d\left( x_{n},x\right) \in B\left( 0,\delta \right) $

holds for all $n\geq N.$

Suppose that $\delta >0$ and define $\varepsilon =\frac{\delta }{2}.$

Choose an integer $N$ such that the inequality

$0\leq d\left( x_{n},x\right) <\varepsilon <\delta $

holds for all $n\geq N.$

Therefore $d\left( x_{n},x\right) \in B\left( 0,\delta \right) $ holds for
all $n\geq N$ and $d\left( x_{n},x\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow
\infty .$

Now assume that $d\left( x_{n},x\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow
\infty .$
I want to prove that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an integer $N$
such that the inequality

$d\left( x_{n},x\right) <\varepsilon $

holds for all $n\geq N.$

Suppose that $\varepsilon >0.$ 
From our assumption we know that there exists an integer $N$ such that the
inequality

$d\left( d\left( x_{n},x\right) ,0\right) <\varepsilon $

for all $n\geq N.$

Using this fact, choose such an integer $N.$

Since we are thinking in $\boldsymbol{R,}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&d\left( d\left( x_{n},x\right) ,0\right)  \\
&=&d\left( x_{n},x\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}

and therefore we have

$d\left( x_{n},x\right) <\varepsilon $

for all $n\geq N.$

This is the first time that I've tried to post tex code on here, so I hope it works. I'm new to the whole tex thing! I think I got most of the inline stuff to work, but I can't figure out to make some of the inequalities go into a center display. The tex command site that I'm looking at says something about using [ and ] to make displays, but it's not working on here.

Any advice or input about my proof would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: [This link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good starting point for writing mathematics here. To get displayed lines, enclose the formula in double rather than single dollar signs. And remember, you can always right-click on a formula here to see how it was coded: select `Show Math As` and then `TeX Commands`.

Comment: Ohh wow, I had no idea that the right-clicking thing existed. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, though you’ve worked a little harder than necessary in the first part. In particular, there was no need to cut $\delta$ in half. Here’s all you need for that direction:

> Suppose that $x_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. But (as you noted later) $d\big(d(x_n,x),0\big)=d(x_n,x)$, so $d\big(d(x_n,x),0\big)<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$, and therefore $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

I’ve followed your lead in using $d$ for both the metric and the usual distance function in $\Bbb R$, but it would probably be better to use the more usual notation:

> Suppose that $x_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. But (as you noted later) $|d(x_n,x)-0|=d(x_n,x)$, so $|d(x_n,x)-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$, and therefore $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The professor that is helping me through this material is old school, and has me state everything in a very meticulous way... I'm more trying to make him happy than be efficient. He'll probably tear holes in my wording anyway, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

the claim is a tautology (a very fundamental one) and its proof is very very short.

The meaning of $x_n\to x$ is: for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ holds that $d(x_n ,x)<\epsilon $.

The meaning of $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ is: for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ holds that $|d(x_n, x)-0|<\epsilon$. But since $|d(x_n,x)-0|=d(x_n,x)$, the two assertions are identical.

Comment: What do you mean by tautology? I've heard it means one statement being made in two different ways, but what is the statement?

The fact that $|d(x_n, x)-0|<\epsilon $ and $d(x_n ,x)<\epsilon $ say the same thing?

Comment: I mean that once you just translate from the English words making up each statement to the mathematical meaning (like I've done above) you get two statements that are identical. (The use of the word tautology in logic has a precise meaning. It is also used the way I use it here, to refer to a proof that only involved a bit of unpacking of the definitions, without any sophisticated arguments.)

Comment: I'm feeling like the methods of proof that you're talking about are coming JUST A LITTLE BIT more naturally, but I still have no idea what "sophisticated arguments" means in the context of the mathematics. For the last few weeks I've felt like I'm due for a general mathematical epiphany... Is that a normal feeling?